# Search blockchain without having own node running?

Tags: solidity, web3js, explorers

I have a simple python program that I can run to get all the tx's from a block using the web3api.  This requires me to run geth and have my node running/listening.

I understand there websites out there that offer API access but they are typically limited.

My question is if I can search through the blocks/data that have already been downloaded to my machine without having to have geth running.

Comment: don't think you cna open the BC data stored on your machine without running geth. so having an RPC endpoint is necessary

Comment: Couldn't you use infura?

Comment: Any client you use to download data of blockchain stores the entire data in some DB, you can traverse the data in that DB to get required data. But it varies from client to client. Geth uses leveldb, parity uses rocksdb

Answer (score 3):

Infura is like having a friend running a node for you
https://infura.io/

Comment: Do you happen to know their api limits or does it vary?  Can't find mention of it on their site.

Comment: AFAIK there are no limits
https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/58#issuecomment-359504174

Comment: Just checked with somebody working in Infura and confirmed there are no limits to the API